# Make lower bitrate(lower resolution) video on concate time using ffmpeg

Tags: c#, asp.net, ffmpeg

I have concated multiple video using ffmpeg but i need lower resolution video(compress it's size) because sometimes videos are too big so it take so much time.

I have used this command :

"ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c copy out.mp4"

Please help for compress video.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if it's time you're trying to save, `copy` will always be the fastest mode. No encoding operation will occur faster. If it's file size, then bitrate `-b:v` is the parameter you want to control.

Comment: I can try to manage bitrate using -b:v command, but still facing this issue.
I have used below command :

strParam = " -f concat -i " + file + " -c copy -b:v 1200k " + strResult;

Comment: If you're copying,bitrate param has no effect. You have to use `-c:v libx264 -b:v 1200k -c:a copy` and remove the `-c copy`.

Comment: Thanks for help, but it's not working

Comment: What's not working? Paste your command and console output!!

Comment: I want any size of mp4 video can concate speedily, but some video work better and some videos which size is big or bitrate is high is not merge.
If yoou have any idea then share it, again thanks for our help

Comment: As I said in the first comment, copy will be the fastest, You can't go faster than that.

Comment: I have not used console , i have used ffmpeg.exe in visual studio and i put there command via visual studio process

Comment: Yes, i read your comment that '-copy' is fastest , but some videos are not merging. Process  goes to infinite mode. I have checked till 20 minute but still process is running. Please give your suggestion

Comment: Need to see console output.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using '-c copy' (which will just remux the video from the source without compression) you can choose an appropriate video encoder to use. As your target is mp4 then you probably want to use libx264 eg:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -vcodec libx264 -preset fast -acodec copy -b:v 3808k
```

This would create a ~ 4mbit video (depending on your source audio), you can experiment with the -b:v param to suit your needs and may find you dont need to alter your resolution.

To alter the resolution a scaling video filter would do the job eg:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -vf scale=-1:720 -vcodec libx264 -preset fast -acodec copy -b:v 3808k
```

Will produce a video with a vertical resolution of 720 and scale the horizontal resolution to match the aspect ratio of the input.

Comment: I have merged two video files. One is 17.02 mb and second is 7.04 mb but it takes too much time and process is going on infinite. I also merged some another video files, it's merged fastest way.

I am not decided what is problem over there.I have also checked your suggestion but i have still facing  same issue.

Please give your suggestion. Thank you for help

Comment: I have used following command:
"ffmpeg -f concat -i " + file + " -vcodec libx264 -preset fast -acodec copy -b:v 3808k out.mp4"
But still is not working.Process is goes to infinite mode

Comment: what is infinite mode? what does the ffmpeg log say? when you say it is not working does that mean the output video is corrupt? are there error messages?